# Retrieve value of child node given attribute

Tags: xml, windows, bash, shell, xmlstarlet

I am trying to retrieve the value of a child node of a given node on a Windows Machine. Suppose I have the following XML structure:

```
<xsd:type name="type1">
    <xsd:example>
      <xsd:description>This is the description of said type1 tag</xsd:description>
    </xsd:example>
</xsd:type>
```

I'd like to retrieve the value in between the xsd:description tag given that it is the child of the xsd:type tag with the name="type1" attribute. In other words, I'd like to retrieve "This is the description of said type1 tag".

On a Mac, I'm able to run the below command to retrieve just that with the following:

```
xml sel -t -v "//xsd:type[@name=\"type1\"]" -n filePath.xml
```

Which then returns: "This is the description of said type1 tag" as expected.

However, when I run the exact same command on my Windows machine, the command returns an empty string. I'm not sure what the differences are between Mac and Windows, but I can't seem to figure out the equivalent Windows command.

Comment: Why do you use the tag `linux` when you are asking about Windows? As you also used the tags `bash` and `shell`, please explain in your question which shell you use on Windows. (Which software did you install?)

Comment: Does the xml document you are using specify a namespace, i.e. does it include the attribute `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` somewhere at the beginning?

Comment: @RobC yes it does. Just to note, this command works on MAC but not on Windows (using the same XML file). I may not know too much about the solution, but it feels like the command ought to change rather than differences in the XML.

Comment: @Bodo thanks for the input. I'm using git bash on Windows.

Comment: @Adam Please [edit] your question and add all clarification or requested information there instead of answering in comments. When I try your command in Git bash, I get `bash: xml: command not found`. This is what I expect. If you don't get this error message, please show the output of `type xml` **in your question**. Did you install anything to get an `xml` command on Windows?

Comment: @Bodo - That's because you probably don't have [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) installed.

Comment: This means the question lacks the information that XMLStarlet is installed and which version of this software is used on both computers. Apparently the versions behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely to be related to not properly defining a namespace.

XML Starlet provides a [`-N`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04.html) option which is described as:

> ```
> -N <name>=<value>     - predefine namespaces (name without 'xmlns:')
>                         ex: xsql=urn:oracle-xsql
> ```

Change your command to the following instead:

```
xml sel -N xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" -t -v "//xsd:type[@name=\"type1\"]//xsd:description/text()" -n filePath.xml
```

**Notes:**

1. The part below was added to predefine the namespace for the XPath expression, so that it addresses the elements in the correct namespace:

   > `-N xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`
2. Also the XPath expression was changed to the following to better address your actual requirement:

   > `"//xsd:type[@name=\"type1\"]//xsd:description/text()"`

   This expression matches the `text()` node of any `xsd:description` element node that is a descendant of any `xsd:type` element node which has a `name="type1"` attribute.